# How to bulletproof Wordpress plugin against jQuery overwriting plugins

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm getting lots of messages that my Wordpress plugin doesn't work. Usually the problem is that lots of poorly written plugins are including jQuery just by echoing `<script src="....>` instead of using Wordpress hooks. When they do that it overwrites currently included jQuery together with all other libraries previously loaded.

Now I've added a warning message when there's no expected jQuery plugin loaded and other plugins should be switched off to see which one could be causing the conflict. I'd like to make my plugin work even if some poorly written one is running and breaking jQuery.

Can I just clone jQuery object to make it completely separate just for my plugin and not being at risk of being overwritten? Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, ask at [wordpress.se]. It's a very good Question and I think I haven't seen this one over there: much more specialists per square pixel  ;) Check the etiquette for [cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667).

Comment: Also linking your wordpress plugin is not such a bad idea because this would show the code. For both sites.

Answer (score 0):

Set a custom variable like

```
var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

then do

```
$jQ(document).ready(function(){
/* code */  
});
```